# Winform c# combobox border is like a hole in my program

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this is a minor thing but it's really annoying.
I have a winform project where I've added a combobox, but the borders is like a hole in my program. If I click on the borders, it navigates me to the window under.

### [image]

**Properties set**

```
this.cbAvailableProjects.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
this.cbAvailableProjects.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cbAvailableProjects.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
this.cbAvailableProjects.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.cbAvailableProjects.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.cbAvailableProjects.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cbAvailableProjects.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 33);
this.cbAvailableProjects.Name = "cbAvailableProjects";
this.cbAvailableProjects.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 25);
this.cbAvailableProjects.TabIndex = 4;
```

Comment: Is there any relevant code to show?  Does that happen on a new form on a new project?

Comment: It is not minor.  Could be a TransparencyKey accident, could be a glass mishap, could be that your UI thread is burning 100% core and never paints the combobox.

Comment: In Designer, can you right click and say "Bring to Front"? Maybe there is some other control that is overlayed somehow. Failing that. I'd try to create a new ComboBox and see if you can get that working correctly, then you can delete the one that is failing.

Comment: It's almost assuredly a transparency issue on the parent.

Comment: It is not burning cpu, i tryid to add a new one, it has the same problem. How can I fix transparency issue?

Comment: If i put a black panel behind it, that do not work either

Answer (score 1):

For those who meet with this problem again:
Change the **TransparencyKey** to none in the **Form's Properties**